# Access Nuxt Context in utils.js for using localePath nuxt-i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, client, nuxt-i18n

I want to use localePath in baseUrl but nuxt context is not available here. Is there any solution to make it possible. Thanks in Advance

```
  axios.create({
    baseURL: `${API_DOMAIN}/${localePath}/${apiURL}`,
    headers: requestHeaders(),
    paramsSerializer: (params) => Qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' }),
  });

export default client;
```

Comment: Where are you here? If it's a plugin, you totally have access to Nuxt's instance.

Comment: @kissu I am not in the plugin, I am in the utils folder -> client.js file. Can I access here the Nuxt context? Is there any method to using a plugin I can access the local path in that file.

Comment: When you call your `.js` file, you can always pass the Nuxt instance as a param to your function like `myCoolFunction(this)`, and use `this` inside of your code to have the instance of Nuxt (even if it's not in a file with the instance baked in).

Comment: @kissu Actually I don't want to pass the nuxt instance as a param, For this, I have to do a lot of changes. Any other solution for this to access the nuxt instance?

Comment: Can't think about anything long term as good sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that one by checking `if(!isServer)`

```js
let localePath = 'en'
const isServer = typeof window === "undefined"
if (!isServer) localePath = window.$nuxt.$store.$i18n.locale

axios.create({
 baseURL: `${API_DOMAIN}/${localePath}/${apiURL}`,
 headers: requestHeaders(),
 paramsSerializer: (params) => Qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' }),
});

export default client;
```